# Database Design for Wix-like Subscription-based Business Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design

Use Case (similar to Wix subscription model)

A user can have many websites. In order to have one website, he needs to buy and maintain a subscription.

So if he wants more websites, he needs to buy and maintain a separate subscription for each of the websites he creates.

I am designing a database for Rails and I am quite confused how the design should be.

Which one is better?

```
Client
has_many :websites
has_many :subscriptions, through: :websites

Website
belongs_to :client
belongs_to :subscription

Subscription
has_many :websites
belongs_to :client
has_many :pricing_plans

PricingPlan
belongs_to :subscription
```

or

```
Client
has_many :websites
has_many :subscriptions, through: :websites

Website
belongs_to :client
has_one :subscription

Subscription
belongs_to :website
belongs_to :client
has_many :pricing_plans

PricingPlan
belongs_to :subscription
```

or is there a better design? What else should I take note of? If the user cancel the subscription, the website must be deactivated too automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, I would go with something like this:

```
Client
has_many :subscriptions
has_many :websites, through: :subscriptions 

Subscription
belongs_to :client
has_one :website
has_one :pricing_plan_subscription
has_one :pricing_plan, through: :pricing_plan_subscription

Website
belongs_to :subscription
has_one :client, through: :subscription

PricingPlan

PricingPlanSubscription
belongs_to: :subscription
has_one: :pricing_plan
```

A client would have many subscriptions and many websites through those subscriptions. Since a client cannot have a website without a subscription, there would be no reason to have this reversed as in your first example.

Also, another key difference in this solution is having `PricingPlan` and `PricingPlanSubscription` vs just `PricingPlan`. The reason for this is that you want to be able to standardize pricing plans and have them be reusable for different users. So the "container" `PricingPlanSubscription` would allow you to associate pricing plans with users and update plans if needed.

To handle "deactivation" I would not destroy the subscription or website, simple add a column to archive. That way you will be able to restore them in the future if needed. You would have to write methods to handle this action of course.

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks for the immense help. But I don't quite get the difference between PricingPlan and PricingPlanSubscription. Hope you can provide some sample attributes for each model to explain the difference between them.

Comment: @RailsNewbie PricingPlan will contain fields like name, cost, terms, etc. The PricingPlanSubscription only exists to link both PricingPlan and Subscription, thus would only contain a pricing_plan_id and a subscription_id. You wouldn't want to have many records in your db for storing the cost of pricing plans because if you want to update it in the future, you would have to locate all the individual pricing plans and update all of their costs accordingly. Having the linked structure in place, you update one entry and all the associated records reflect the update. Make a little more sense?

Comment: If I wish to integrate stripe, will pricing plan be necessary?

Comment: If you only have one pricing plan, then no. You can store any data you need in the subscription itself. Having a pricing plan table would be beneficial if you intended to have different types of plans for different service offerings.